# Problem parsing with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the following web page [link](http://www.etsy.com/teams/list). 
Code below:

```
import urllib2
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.etsy.com/teams/list'
source = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
print soup.prettify()

print len(soup('h3')) #to print the no of occurances of h3 
h3s = soup.findAll('h3') #finding the same as above
print len(h3s)
```

The problem is, it prints 1. while the web page contains atleast 10 'h3'.I couldn't figure out where the problem lies
I am using python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 3.0.7

Comment: For the record, BeautifulSoup 3.2.0 gives me 12 h3s with your code (the last two are in some locale-setting nagging overlay).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) instead:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.etsy.com/teams/list')
>>> len(doc.xpath('//h3'))
<<< 10
```

Comment: thank you.Will try using lxml and do you have any idea why BeautifulSoup doesn't give proper result for the above case?

Comment: No, afaik that should work. All I could suggest is trying a different version of BeautifulSoup, or preferably using lxml instead.